# What is the definition of "solipsized?"

Tags: meaning, literature, lolita

It seems like only "Lolita" uses this word.

According to Google, solipsism is "the view or theory that the self is all that can be known to exist."  From this definition, I conclude that for one to be solipsized means that they only acknowledge their own existence.

Comment: What's the question here?  You've provided a definition and an interpretation of that definition.  What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a quirk of Nabokov's phrasing that the most accurate rendition in English relies on ad-hoc "verbification" to succinctly capture the sense more easily expressed in Russian.

From [*Bloom, 1993*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=brOwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22Lolity%20byla%20blagopoluchno%22&dq=%22Lolity%20byla%20blagopoluchno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eVlnVP2RGtDWauGGgPgH&redir_esc=y) - selection of literary criticism focusing on Vladimir Nabokov's controversial character...

> *It is a measure of Humbert's perspicacity that he is sufficiently aware of what he is doing to say that "Lolita had been safely solipsized";
>
>    the Russian translation makes the point even more bluntly: "**Real'nost' Lolity byla blagopoluchno otmenena,**" which means, literally, "**Lolita's reality was successfully cancelled**"*

I assume the intended sense is *"Since Lolita isn't **real**, I can do what I like with her"*. It's a rather obscure philosophical context, so it's no surprise few Anglophones have found reason to promote this particular "credible, but unlikely" verb usage.

In practice (and somewhat less metaphysically) we tend to base this kind of rationalization on *"Since [victim] isn't **human**, I can do what I like to her/him/it"* (we [***dehumanize***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dehumanising) the victim, rather than philosophically rationalize her into complete "non-existence").

Comment: Original Russian? Lolita was written in English.

Comment: @bwv869: My bad - you're quite right. But since Nabokov was a Russian speaker by birth, wrote many *earlier* novels in Russian, and presumably primarily tended to *think* in Russian, I think the point I was making is still substantially valid. So I've just edited out the misleading reference to "Original Russian" - thanks for flagging it up.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler answer.

Humbert wanted Lolita to withdraw from any interest in the outside world and instead become more interested in her own needs and wants. This way Humbert would not have to worry about interference with his "sexual dance" from any authorities and the like, who they would come into occasional contact with as they traveled.

Solipsists were known to question whether anything outside the observer's mind really existed. This invariably led to the elevation of the person him/herself and not of those in the world outside. Solipsizing, a word the Russian writer Nabokov and lover of the English language apparently formed himself, seems to be a method used by Humbert of drawing Lolita into herself so that the protagonist could subsequently have even more control of her limited external experiences and hence participate in his "marriage" rather safely.

Comment: It find this explanation to be more direct and more recognizably Nabokovian than the one proposed by Bloom. Even the Russian rewording "Lolita's reality was successfully cancelled" fits more nicely into this explanation if one interprets this phrase to describe a reality cancelled *for* Lolita, *from the point of view* of Lolita, rather than from the point of view of Humbert. As you say, Humbert's intention was to cause Lolita to withdraw within herself, to assume a total self-absorption which would distract her from Humbert's own activity.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a struggle to get from **solipsism**, -- as you say the belief that only the self can be known to exist, -- to a useful active verbal form as suggested by **solipsized**.

You are right that the word is rare and most references seem to be to *Lolita*. In this context, soplipsized means to make something a part of the self. The protagonist is faced by overwhelming forces apparently external to himself, their existence beyond his control, and through a process of **solipsizing** (however that is achieved: I've not read the book, but can guess) he makes them a part of himself, and so apparently more controllable.

So here it is used to mean, roughly, "to make a part of the self", with the secondary implication, by its etymology, that this is the authentic mode of a thing existing.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have it here: Lolita has been made unreal to Humbert. At the start of chapter 14, 2 pages after "Lolita had been safely solipsized" Humbert goes on to say "Lolita was safe - and I was safe. What I had madly possessed was not she, but my own creation, another, fanciful Lolita - perhaps, more real than Lolita; overlapping, encasing her; floating between me and her, and having no will, no consciousness - indeed, no life of her own."

Answer (score 0):

The words "encompassed," "enveloped," "subsumed," and "absorbed" come to mind, although they don't necessarily convey any vulgarity or violence.

Comment: You should explain how these chosen words fit as a definition of solipsized.

Answer (score -1):

Nabokov’s solipsized recalls the Russian word ***пошлость*** (poshlost). It now stands for vulgarity - but once was a midway between *vulgar* and *decent*. In his book on **Gogol**, Nabokov notes how Gogol was a virtuous user of poshlost as a middle-of-the-road adjective, specially in “Dead Souls”. And notes:

"The Russian language is capable of expressing with a merciless word a defect that is widespread, and for which the other three European languages ​​I know have no specific term."

So I see solipsized as an extension, into English, of a flexibility that marks Russian - and pushes on all readers the task of picking his or her choice of meaning.

Comment: Can it be explained more explicitly what the connection between this word and *solipsized* is, and why that connection is more illuminating than what appears in the answers that have already been offered?

Comment: Sorry: I also found the previous answers more illuminating on solipsized. It just occurred to me how this discussion sheds light on the richness of languages, and how I guess Nabokov’s multi-language mind was present when he wrote in English (mixing some French in it). Sure, mine was a lateral point..